# Deployment of multiple Jenkins slaves on a Mac

Tags: macos, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

I have read a lot about running multiple slaves on a host machine that has the Jenkins master running on it, however, I am a bit confused on how to move forward. I want the Jenkins server to call slaves whenever it is possible in order to distribute the workload. In my case, each Jenkins slave will be building scripts from Unity3d projects. I have installed an Ubuntu VM on my mac where the master Jenkins server is and would like to know how to set it up.

Would I use another OS on the slave VM?

In addition, I am running the VM on VirtualBox, is this the best option or would another VM be better fit for this job?

Finally, if someone knows how to set this up, would it be possible for them to state how to set up a slave on the same machine as the server and connect both of them through ssh?

Comment: There is no need to run a VM just for a slave, unless you need that VM for OS/sandboxing reasons. You can have a master node, and multiple slaves, all on the same physical host, or you can distribute the slaves to different physical hosts (to spread the load). Running a slave inside a VM on the same host as the master does not help in load distribution at all. The only reason to do that would be for OS/Sandboxing

Comment: Oh! Thanks for that. Then, how can you deploy a slave on the same host? I have been trying but can't get it to work. My jenkins master builds when a commit is pushed in to gitlab and would like to run some scripts on a slave, how would you go on to do that?